# Probability of a 5 card hand from a standard 52 deck containing all 4 suits

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The answer to this is $\dfrac{4 {13 \choose 2} {13 \choose 1} {13 \choose 1} {13 \choose 1}}{ {52 \choose 5}}$,

but what I'm trying to figure out is why  $\dfrac{{13\choose 1}{13\choose 1}{13\choose 1}{13\choose 1}{48 \choose 1}}{{52\choose 5}}$  doesn't work, because it also seems logical to me.

Can somebody explain why the latter doesn't work?

Comment: $4\binom{13}{2}=4\frac{13\cdot 12}{1\cdot 2}$ which can be expressed as $\frac{48}213=\frac12\binom{48}1\binom{13}1$. That should've pointed that you're counting twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed expression does "double-counting."  When you calculate $\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{48}{1}$, you are making a tick mark for the choice $2\spadesuit$, K$\heartsuit$, $7\diamondsuit$, $8\clubsuit$, Q$\heartsuit$.

But you are also making a tick mark for the choice $2\spadesuit$, Q$\heartsuit$, $7\diamondsuit$, $8\clubsuit$, K$\heartsuit$, which is the same hand.

But all is not lost! Every hand gets double counted by your formula, so to get the right answer we just divide by $2$. This kind of deliberate overcount-then-adjust can be a useful technique.

Comment: Can you explain why each hand is being counted twice?

Comment: Your formula has us chooe a spade, a heart, a diamond, a club, then another card, and counts the choices, $13$ at stage $1$, another $13$ at stage $2$, and so on. But as the example in the answer illustrates, for every "good" $5$-card hand, there are **two** choices among those counted by $(13)^4(48)$ that lead to that hand. So your formula double-counts the good hands.